# C# Multithreading - Threads don't run

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am teaching myself C# from my usual C++ programming and now I'm doing threads.

The following simple code compiles fine and should output beeps on a loop via threads for 30 seconds.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;

class BeepSample
{
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
    static extern bool Beep(uint dwFreq, uint dwDuration);

    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Testing PC speaker...");
        for (uint i = 100; i <= 20000; i++)
        {
            var BeepThread = new Thread(delegate() { Beep(i, 30000); });            
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Testing complete.");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Only problem is the threads don't seem to work.

I know I am missing something basic.

Any ideas?

Comment: *As soon as you type `new Thread()`, it's over; your project already has legacy code.* Concurrency in C# Cookbook, @StephenCleary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Only problem is the threads don't seem to work.

This aspect is clear from the part that you have not started the threads for them to do anything

> Code has many other issues:

- Closure issue, needs further modification as

  ```
  for (uint i = 100; i <= 20000; i++)
  {
    int icopy = i;
    var BeepThread = new Thread(delegate() { Beep(icopy, 30000); });    
    BeepThread.Start();        
  }
  ```
- `Thread` class will start the `foreground threads` and each logical processor core has capacity to process one thread at a time and each `Thread` is a very costly resource for the `computation and memory` as it needs allocation of `Thread Environment Block, Kernel Stack Memory, User Stack Memory`, the current code even if it runs, will kill your system and you mostly have to kill the process to come out of it
- `Console.ReadLine();` will only block the `Main Thread / Ui Thread`, others threads being foreground will go on even if `Main thread / Ui thread` exits and not blocked, ideal way to block is calling `Join` on each Thread object, which will ask Main thread to wait till its complete
- One of the preferred way to re-write the same code is using the Task Parallel Library:

  ```
   Parallel.For(100, 20000,
   , new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism =  
  Environment.ProcessorCount } 
  i =>
  {
     int icopy = i;
      Beep(icopy, 30000);
  });
  ```

Benefits:

- Code doesn't create so many threads and kill the system
- Works on `thread pool (Background threads)` and use only required number of threads are invoked and max number never exceeds the `Processor count` of the system and would be mostly far lesser, as threads are reused since there's no major long running computation
- Automatically blocks `Main thread / Ui Thread`

Comment: Best possible answer. Learned more about threading than expected. Thanks.

Comment: Check this book mentioned above too "Concurrency in C# Cookbook", @StephenCleary, to get the good understanding of Concurrency in C#

Comment: You may accept the answer, if you find it useful for your use case

Answer (score 3):

Your forgot to start thread [MSDN link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x4c42hc(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
for (uint i = 100; i <= 20000; i++)
{
    var BeepThread = new Thread(delegate() { Beep(i, 30000); });
    BeepThread.Start();
}
```

However that looks suspicious. Why would you need 19900 threads? Probably you want to have 1 thread, that has a loop inside and pauses for short periods to output different frequency through beeper.

Comment: you should also keep references to `Thread` objects so that they are not `GC`ed before they are done

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thanks guys. Had gone for lunch.

I implemented...

```
for (uint i = 500; i <= 550; i++)
    {
        uint icopy = i;
        var BeepThread = new Thread(delegate() { Beep(icopy, 30000); });
        BeepThread.Start(); 
    }
```

Which worked great.

As predicted the threads did not terminate after the main thread was executed but it does what I want which is awesome.

Bless y'all.